# Accessing a Linux box for forget username and password

Tags: linux

I have a physical linux box running some services. I have no any login information for that linux box.

How do I get access to the box and check all the services running on that box? It is not just reseting the password I need to know the services running too on the linux box.

Comment: ask the system administrator?

Comment: That guy is no more working with us thats why I needed to figure out some thing in that box.

Comment: Ok above answer gives me access how to figure out services running on the box?

Comment: rebooting to recover the root password will stop the current services; hopefully they're configured to restart at boot.

Comment: But I guess even a new sys admin will have to do that so lets see if all goes good.

Comment: You could `nmap` the box to see if it has any services running that would accept network connections

Answer (score 0):

To do without a live cd:

0- Print or write this tutorial.

1- Reboot the machine

2- Press 'e' over the distro option on boot (some versions of grub dont have the e option to edit, but another key)

3- Go to the line started with linux word (Use the keyboard)

4- Press the END key to go to the end of that line.

5- Type [space]init=/bin/bash (please don't type space, just do a space)

6- Type CTRL+X or F10 (thats depends on your grub version)

7- A linux terminal will open, so execute this commands:

```
#mount -o remount,rw none /
```

(yes you should write none)

```
#passwd root
#passwd youruser
```

Enter the new root or youruser password, and that is it. (in some systems root is not the admin, because it is disabled)

And now umount the partition and reboot:

```
#umount / 
#reboot -f
```

That is it!

Answer (score 0):

Now that you know how to have root acces, try these two commands :

```
chkconfig --list    (RedHat, SuSE, ?) 

service --status-all   (OS using systemd, SuSE, ?) 

ps fax           (to list processes grouped by descendant)
```

Filesystem names can gives you information, main application uses their own filesystem (for instance Oracle is often mounted on a .../oracle directory)

```
df
mount
```

Application are run on specific user ID.

```
cat /etc/passwd
cat /etc/group
```

Some jobs may be running periodically, and you can miss them with the `ps`  command read the crontab files. To list the crontab files :

```
find /var/spool/cron/crontabs
```

Looking for log files is a good indication :

```
find / | grep log   (works only on full filenames containing "log")
```

This will give you information on the running services. You will have to dig in the services configuration to know what they are doing. You will need to check for instance what application is hosted on the apache-tomcat server or what service is giving the `xinetd` server.